# Using jQAssistant for checking that all public EJB methods are annotated with @RolesAllowed or @PermitAll

Tags: java, neo4j, ejb, cypher, jqassistant

I want to write a [Cypher](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html) rule for [jQAssistant](http://jqassistant.org/) that checks whether all public EJB methods are annoated with either `@RolesAllowed` or `@PermitAll`.

Is this possible? Since I'm new to the Cypher query language of Neo4j I have problems formulating the "not exists" condition in Cypher to find "all public methods in EJB classes (= classes that have the `@Stateless` annotation) that are not annotated with `@RolesAllowed` or `@PermitAll`".

Comment: @ingrid obviously your answer is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is putting the not exists part in where clause, e.g.

```
match
  (:Stateless)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)
where
  m.visibility ="public"
  and not (
    (m)-[:ANNOTATED_BY]->()-[:OF_TYPE]->(:Type{fqn:"...PermitAll")
    or
    ... 
  )
return
  m
```

Hope this illustrates the idea, it's quite difficult to write this stuff on a tablet. I can give you a more advanced example next week.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Great to read! The solution could be even more elegant by creating concepts for PermitAll and AllowedRoles, they could even be candidates for the jQA EJB3 plugin.